# Calling Google Cloud KMS from AWS Lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, google-cloud-kms

I'm new to Google's Cloud services and to Java, but I'm trying to set up a Java function on AWS Lambda that makes a call to Google Cloud KMS. I have working Java code locally, but from what I can tell the only way to authenticate the Google client is to set an environment variable with the path to a JSON file containing your credentials. I can do that easily locally when triggering my Java function - I just set the environment variable pointing to a file on my computer when running the code. Can anyone give me any pointers for how to do that in Lambda where all I seem to be able to do is upload a single .jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to store the JSON file in AWS Secret Manager and then retrieve the JSON file at function boot by authenticating to the AWS Secret Manager. Then you should configure the Google client library to use that credential contents.

Alternatively (more complex but also more secure) would be to [configure GCP as an OIDC provider for AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html) and then create an AWS role with permission to call GCP KMS directly - no credential file required.

Comment: Your first solution is basically what my friend and I landed on when discussing this last night. I'm not sure how the internals of the Google client library work, and it seems to only want a file path and not the raw credentials, so we thought the easiest solution would be to save a temporary file and write the contents of an ENV variable or AWS Secrets Manager secret to that file before calling Google KMS. That basic idea works locally, so I should be able to adapt it for use on Lambda.